# Сохранение регистров при вызове функций

Tags: функции, ассемблер, x86

Не могу понять одну вещь в соглашениях о вызове, почему часть регистров должна сохраняться вызывающей стороной? Какая в этом выгода? Ведь за пределами функции неизвестно какие регистры она будет менять, а какие - нет. Значит вызывающей стороне приходится всегда сохранять и восстанавливать каждый такой регистр, проделывая бесполезную, лишнюю работу для тех, которые в функции не используются. Разве не логичнее было бы, чтобы вызываемая функция сама сохраняла и восстанавливала все регистры?

Так зачем нужно это разделение, при котором часть регистров сохраняется внутри функции, а часть - снаружи? Ради чего это сделано?

Comment: а где это написано, что они должны сохраняться вызывающей стороной?

Comment: Ну например вот тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2017#callercallee-saved-registers - `The registers RAX, RCX, RDX, R8, R9, R10, R11 are considered volatile and must be considered destroyed on function calls`

Comment: Нет это не говорит о том, что RAX нужно сохранять, это подразумевает, что вы как правило должны использовать эти регистры для текущих операций и не хранить в них "длительных" данных. Посмотрите например ассемблер, который генерит C/C++.

Comment: В некоторых соглашениях вызываемая сторона ответственна за сохранение и восстановление состояния. Но если вызываемая сторона по какой-то причине соглашение не соблюдает, то программа упадёт или поведёт себя непредсказуемо. Контроль с вызывающей стороны надёжнее и безопаснее.

Comment: мы обсуждаем volatile регистры, а есть ещё которые вызываемая сторона должны сохранять, volatile обычно используются между вызовами сторонних функций

Comment: @t3f, чтобы не сохранять значения регистров, вызывающая сторона может просто не хранить ничего важного в них на момент вызова функции. Между вызовами функций с ними можно делать что угодно, но результат операций должен сохраняться куда-то, например в "неволатильные" регистры (список по той же ссылке) или в стековые или глобальные переменные, или просто передаваться в саму функцию в качестве параметра.

Comment: Но вопрос то не о том, как работать с volatile регистрами (это и так очевидно). Вопрос о том, какая польза от них?

Comment: @t3f, потому и существует две группы регистров - volatile и not-volatile, что для volatile регистров функция не должна заботиться, чтобы восстановить их значение перед выходом, а для non-volatile вызывающий код может быть уверен, что после вызова функции значения этих регистров останется таким же как и до вызова. В целом это позволяет минимизировать количество требуемых операций сохранения регистров еще куда-то (чем если бы все регистры были волатильными или неволатильными).

Answer (score 0):

Итак, я нашёл ситуацию, в которой сохранение вызывающим кодом имеет явные преимущества перед сохранением в вызываемых функциях. Это последовательность из нескольких вызовов, например:

```
call func1
call func2
...
call funcN
```

Если каждая из этих функций использует одни и те же регистры, то при сохранении в функциях оно будет выполняться в каждой из них (т. е. для N функций будет выполнено N сохранений и восстановлений).
А в случае volatile регистров, сохраняемых вызывающей стороной, в такой ситуации будет достаточно только одного сохранения (перед вызовом первой функции) и одного восстановления (после возврата из последней).